# Por que NaN === NaN retorna false em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, comparação, nan

Em JavaScript, ao realizar a comparação de dois valores `NaN` (*Not-A-Number*), o resultado é `false`. No entanto isso não ocorre com valores como `null` e `undefined`.

```js
console.log(NaN === NaN, null === null, undefined === undefined)
```

A MDN fala sobre o assunto ao explicar a necessidade da função [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) para verificar se um valor equivale a `NaN`:

> Ao contrário de todas as outras possibilidades de valores no JavaScript, não é possivel confiar nos operadores de igualdade (== e ===) para determina se o valor é NaN ou não, porque ambos, NaN == NaN e NaN === NaN, terá como valor de retorno: false. Daí a necessidade da funçao isNAN.

No entanto isso ainda não responde por que `NaN === NaN` retorna `false`.

Sendo assim, qual a razão deste comportamento? Até onde eu sei, isso está relacionado com a coerção de tipos em JavaScript (corrijam-me se eu estiver errado), porém gostaria de entender o que acontece com mais exatidão.

Comment: Não tem a ver com JavaScript diretamente, esse comportamento vem da norma técnica de números de ponto flutuante (IEEE 754)

Comment: Cara não sei se você tem interesse em saber sobre a matemática por trás disso, mas em resumo o fato de Nan === Nan retornar falso é porque a norma [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) (que o javascript segue em sua implementação) tem essa definição.
Nela você pode encontrar mais sobre a motivação por trás, os cálculos, conceitos matemáticos e etc que explicam o porque disso.

Comment: É estranho, né?! isso pq `typeof NaN` é `'number'` e `null === null` é `true`, apesar de `typeof null` ser `'object'` e `{} === {}` ser `false`.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, todo `null` é o “mesmo” objeto, aí dá `true`. Os dois objetos literais aí são diferentes, então retorna `false`, mas se você fizer `let a = {}; a === a;`, terá `true`. E sobre o `NaN` não poder ser comparável, não tem bem a ver com o tipo, mas sim sobre a sua própria existência e as consequências disso. [Veja mais aqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/7445826)